# Div over an image for HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have some text to be viewed over an image. I can achieve this using `margin` or `position` but since it is an HTML for email, these are not working as I needed. Below is my code for it.

```
<div style="padding-right:25px;padding-left:20px">
  <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px">
    <table style="text-align:center;border:1px solid #ddd;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <div style="width: 100%;">
                    <img src="myimage.png"/>
                    <div style="margin-top:-280px;font-size: 20px"><b><font face="Calibri">Text</font></b></div>
                    <div style="font-size:48px;line-height:58px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:40px;"><span><font face="Calibri">abc</font></span></div>
                </div>
             </td>
         </tr></tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "it is not working as needed"... what is not working...?
I created an example for you... tell me what is not working?
https://jsfiddle.net/15g1u7jn/

Comment: Also, very ugly to write inline css styling..create css classes.

Comment: Its for Email template and how do you suggest me to add a new css file and all. Also negative margin wont work in email. Anyway below answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [Campaignmonitor.com article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/06/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/) Use a background image the entire email applied to a table like so:

```
<table background="bg.png"><tr><td><!-- TEXT HERE --></td></tr></table>
```

And CSS for fallback:

```
body {
    background-image: url('bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Additionally, they reference a tool to make "bullet proof email background" https://backgrounds.cm/

Comment: Thanks for the css. It worked perfectly after I remove the `repeat-y`.